# Problem installing node js and npm on Manjaro linux

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, manjaro

**OS: Manjaro**

I installed **npm** and **nodejs** by this command: `sudo pacman -S nodejs npm`

after installation i have an error:

```
~]$ npm -v
node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.67: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
~]$ node --version
node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.67: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Install **nvm** (*Node Version Manager*)

   ```
    yay -S nvm
   ```
2. Load **nvm**

   ```
    source /usr/share/nvm/init-nvm.sh
   ```
3. You can also add the above line in your environment file such as `.bashrc` so you won’t have to do it every time.
4. Install **Node.js** and **npm**

   ```
    nvm -g install npm
   ```
5. Test your setup – open a new terminal and install a package using **npm**

   ```
    $ nvm use stable
    $ nvm -g install browser-sync
    $ browser-sync start --server
   ```

Comment: on the 3rd point, he gives me the fact that I did not specify the command / flag correctly. using the command suggested reverts me to the original problem.```nvm install-latest-npm
Attempting to upgrade to the latest working version of npm...
node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.67: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Unable to obtain node version.
```

Comment: use sudo while using npm commands. and also there's a mistake..please use npm instead of nvm

Comment: @GulshanYadav. In 4th point, nvm install npm too?

Answer (score 2):

I found that you need to install both nodejs and npm from the package manager. If you first install npm however, node is automatically installed as a dependency.

> `yay -S npm`

Answer (score 1):

**Installing:**

```
pamac install nodejs

pacman -S nodejs
```

refer : https://discover.manjaro.org/packages/nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Modified from Gulshan Yadav's answer.

1. Install **nvm** (Node Version Manager)

```
sudo pacman -S nvm
```

2. Load **nvm** & add executable to **bashrc**

```
source /usr/share/nvm/init-nvm.sh
echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"' | tee -a ~/.bashrc
```

3. Install **Node.js** and **npm**

```
nvm install stable
```

4. Test your setup

```
npm install -g nativefier
nativefier --name Deepl "https://deepl.com"
cd Deepl-linux-x64
./Deepl
```